# Can I construct an enum of enums and have a method switch the internal enum based on a variable

Tags: java, enums, switch-statement

Lets say I have an enum like below:

```
    public enum Env {

    holding, integration, staging, production;

    public enum Holding {
        THE_SAME_ENUM("Some String1, "Another String1");

        String name;
        String uuid;

        Holding(String name, String uuid) { this.name = name; this.uuid = uuid; }

        public String getName() {return name;}

        public String getData() {return uuid;}
    }

    public enum Integration {

        THE_SAME_ENUM("Some String2, "Another String2");

        String name;
        String uuid;

        Integration(String name, String uuid) { this.name = name; this.uuid = uuid; }

        public String getName() {return name;}

        public String getData() {return uuid;}
    }

    public enum Staging {
        THE_SAME_ENUM("Some String3, "Another String3");

        String name;
        String uuid;

        Staging(String name, String uuid) { this.name = name; this.uuid = uuid; }

        public String getName() {return name;}

        public String getData() {return uuid;}
    }

    public enum Production {
        THE_SAME_ENUM("Some String4, "Another String4");

        String name;
        String uuid;

        Production(String name, String uuid) { this.name = name; this.uuid = uuid; }

        public String getName() {return name;}

        public String getData() {return uuid;}
    }
}
```

Then in a method, I would like to do something like this:

```
Env env;
switch(System.getEnv()) {
    case holding:
        env = Env.holding;
    case integration:
        env = Env.integration;
    case staging:
        env = Env.staging;
    case production:
        env = Env.production;

    //Expecting "Some String(1)or(2)or(3)or(4)"
    System.out.println(env.THE_SAME_ENUM.getName());
}
```

I would really just like to change the type based on an environment variable and then use the settings that I have hard coded based on the environment. I have not found a way to achieve this. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Sorry but I am not sure what you are really trying to do. It looks like [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Based on your example you can simply add `name` and `uuid` to main enum rather than creating series of inner enum for each enum value so instead of `env.THE_SAME_ENUM.getName()` you could simply use `env.getName()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how I ended up solving the issue. Each parameter to the enum represents separate environments, and I just use getter methods to return the correct id per environment.

```
public enum EnvironmentIds {

USER_MANAGER_CHANGED("e29e902c","28a6e01c", "281916f6"),
USER_ADDED_TO_GROUP("5059020b", "f039fc37", "0e480029"),
USER_CREATED("d9bc6a0c", "f26f0a23", "9261f53a"),
USER_REMOVED_FROM_GROUP("fc30b97c", "15528295", "c08af3b2");


String holdingId;
String productionId;
String stagingId;

EnvironmentIds(String holdingId, String stagingId, String productionId) {
    this.holdingId = holdingId;
    this.stagingId = stagingId;
    this.productionId = productionId;
}

public String getId(String environment) {
    switch(environment) {
        case "holding":
            return getHoldingId();
        case "production":
            return getProductionId();
        case "staging":
            return getStagingId();
        default:
            return null;
    }
}
public String getHoldingId() {return holdingId;}

public String getProductionId() {return productionId;}

public String getStagingId() {return stagingId;}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You probably want something along the lines of this

```
public enum Env {

    holding("Some String1", "Another String1"),
    integration("Some String2", "Another String2"), 
    staging("Some String3", "Another String3"), 
    production("Some String4", "Another String4");

    String name;
    String uuid;
    Env(String name, String uuid) { this.name = name; this.uuid = uuid; }

        public String getName() {return name;}

        public String getData() {return uuid;}
    }
}
```

Comment: I also though about it at first, but it looks like OP is aware of this possibility (based on inner enums code). Anyway fields should most probably be private here, even if in OP example they aren't.